# Referencing all Classes which extend from a root Class - Java

Tags: java, class, oop, interface

Suppose I have a Class called `Data` which has a single variable `var1`

Then I have a Class called `Data2` which extends `Data` which has an additional variable - `var2`.

Then `Data3` extends `Data2` with added variable `var3` and so on.

Now I have an `ArrayList` which needs to take in a `Datax` object (ie. `Data1`, `Data2` or `Data3`), but cannot take in any other object.

So using the generic `Object` class can't work here.

Is there a way of achieving this? Maybe I'm approaching this all wrong. I've tried messing around with interfaces but my `OOP` knowledge is quite poor.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**

Apologies for not mentioning this previously. The reason I can't use generic `Object`s inside the classes is because all `Datax` classes need to be serialized using XML library and it doesn't support generic values.

Comment: *"Is there a way of achieving this?"* Achieving what? So far, you're looking for `ArrayList<Data>`, which can hold instances of all of those classes. But then *using* those instances for anything that `Data` can't do requires `instanceof` and casting, which is ugly and can usually be avoided. What's the actual goal?

Comment: See my edit. The main purpose of this is to have an xml root which has a list of `Data` elements. But each `Data` element may have a varied number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create marker interface.

```
interface IDataObject {
}
```

Make `Data1` class implements `IDataObject`.

```
class Data1 implements IDataObject {
....
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
List<IDataObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Data1());
list.add(new Data2());
list.add(new Data3());
```

**UPD**

If all your `Datax` classes have same parent you can avoid interfaces and do this

```
List<? super Data1> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new Data1());
data.add(new Data2());
data.add(new Data3());
```

Here `Data1` is the parent class for all `Datax` classes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a problem with this approach, see my edit. I like the idea of this `super` class though#

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance seems to form a list on itself. For that one does not need inheritance and can simplify all.

```
public class Data {
    Data previous;
    Object var;

    public Data(Object var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public Data(Object var, Data previous) {
        this.var = var;
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}

Data data = new Data("a");
data = new Data("b", data);
data = new Data("c", data);
```

And

```
data.var -> "a"
data.previous.var -> "b"
data.previous.previous.var -> "c"
data.previous.previous.previous -> null

data: -> "a" -> "b" -> "c"
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution. But it seems like the `Object var` might not be serialized correctly. See my edit. Apologies for not mentioning this in original post

Comment: No problem; serialization often has a hook to do ones own serialization for a specific class. I hope the library has that functionality. Otherwise you would need to do an additional serialization. By the way JAXB with annotations and XML is nice.